# Passar dados entre select

Tags: javascript, html5, html-select

Estou tentando fazer com que o dado selecionado em um `select múltiple` possa passar para o outro select clicando no botão `>>`, mas não consigo.
Será que existe alguma funcionalidade em HTML5 que possa resolver isso ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<select multiple="multiple">
     <optgroup label="Manhã">
      <option>07:00 - 08:00</option>
      <option>08:00 - 09:00</option>
      <option>09:00 - 10:00</option>
      <option>10:00 - 11:00</option>
      <option>11:00 - 12:00</option>
     </optgroup>
     <optgroup label="Tarde">
      <option>12:00 - 13:00</option>
      <option>13:00 - 14:00</option>
      <option>14:00 - 15:00</option>
      <option>15:00 - 16:00</option>
      <option>16:00 - 17:00</option>
      <option>17:00 - 18:00</option>
     </optgroup>
    </select>
    
    <input type="submit" value=">>">
    
    <select multiple="multiple">
     
    </select>
```

Comment: Você terá que usar javascript para isso, você já fez algo? Se sim poste seu código

Comment: @AndersonHenrique não só fiz o html que está mostrando na imagem :/

Comment: Poste o seu HTML também, fica mais fácil de deixarmos o exemplo mais realistico

Comment: @AndersonHenrique feito !

Comment: ótimo, calma ai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue a funcionalidade desejada, básicamente mudei o botão do tipo *input* para *button*, pois você não está submetendo nada, então ele não necessita ser do tipo *submit*, logo após isso defini *id's* para os seus *selects* um eu chamei de *leftBox* e o outro de *rightBox*, depois adicionei um *onClick* no botão que chama a função *appendSelect* do javascript, essa função irá pegar o que você selecionou na caixa esquerda e inserir na da direita usando o *innerHTML*. Repare que no innerHTML eu concateno "+=" para pegar o anterior e somar com os itens novos

**Edit**

Observando melhor sua pergunta vi que você quer remover de um e passar ao outro,para isso o mesmo método de cima será usado a unica diferença é que removeremos a partir do *selectedIndex* da caixa da esquerda, depois de inserir na da direita usando o *remove*

```js
function appendSelect(){
  const leftBox = document.getElementById('leftBox')
  const rightBox = document.getElementById('rightBox');
  rightBox.innerHTML += `<option>${leftBox.value}</option>`;
  const selected = leftBox.options.selectedIndex;
  leftBox.remove(selected)
}
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple" id='leftBox'>
     <optgroup label="Manhã">
      <option>07:00 - 08:00</option>
      <option>08:00 - 09:00</option>
      <option>09:00 - 10:00</option>
      <option>10:00 - 11:00</option>
      <option>11:00 - 12:00</option>
     </optgroup>
     <optgroup label="Tarde">
      <option>12:00 - 13:00</option>
      <option>13:00 - 14:00</option>
      <option>14:00 - 15:00</option>
      <option>15:00 - 16:00</option>
      <option>16:00 - 17:00</option>
      <option>17:00 - 18:00</option>
     </optgroup>
    </select>
    
    <button onClick="appendSelect()">>></button>
    
    <select multiple="multiple" id='rightBox'>
     
    </select>
```